# Computed code for some fields are not working in D8

Tags: 8, entities

I have a content type with **6** computed fields in it. Out of them only **2** are working ( That means trying to parse the php code given in the computed field settings). For other fields its not even entering to the php code given in the computed code. The type of the computed code is  varchar(32) for everyone.

Any idea why this happens, or how could i solve this issue?

[image]

[image]

Comment: I've never used computed fields, so this is half question/half answer. How this is supposed to work with caching? When the node content in the database is not changed, the node is delivered from cache and the fields are not computed again.

Comment: I dont know with caching ,But the computed code (php code)is rendered when the content type is saved . Its given as computed code because it won't show in the front end , it will be processed automatically in the background and saved .

Comment: I only see one line of code, but this wouldn't work with this concept, because the current user on save is the node author and not the user who views the node.

Comment: Yea , it works for some other fields . A single line of code or multiple with exit works . It doesnt matter who modifed the computed code . Here am the admin and the user who modify the content type node . So it works both side .

Comment: Ignore , i installed the new version **8.x-2.0-alpha4** and is now working fine .